# How to declare literal object with interface?

Tags: typescript

I would like to define a literal object that implements an interface.
So I wrote something like this

```
interface MyInterface {
  update: () => void;
}

class MyClass {
  a: MyInterface = {
    update: function(){},
    func2: function(){}
  }
}
```

But this gives me an error that type of `a` is not assignable to `MyInterface`.
Is there a way how to say `a` only implements the interface?

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a syntax to declare that an object literal extends an interface. It is generally not needed. If `a` implements the `update()` function properly then Typescript will recognise that it extends `MyInterface` and you can use it as such, even though it isn't tagged.

If you just want this for code documentation purposes the best solution is to explicitly define a new type for `a` which extends `MyInterface` and define the additional properties. However, if you *really* want Typescript to enforce that an object literal extends `MyInterface` at the point of definition, then there is a workaround. You can use a generic function to assert the interface constraint. Something like this:

```
interface MyInterface {
  update: () => void;
}

const inferAs = <U,>() => <T extends U>(v:T) => v

class MyClass {
  a = inferAs<MyInterface>()({
    update: function(){},
    func2: function(){}
  })
}
```

That is the closest you can get to what you are asking for.

Comment: This answer could use a reference to [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) and how to avoid it.  Also note that you don't need a curried `inferAs` function here.  All function return values are currently non-fresh (at least until and unless [microsoft/TypeScript#241](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/241) is addressed) so any identity function should work with the annotation here, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/DmMXrN).

Comment: @jcalz The identity function completely hides `func2`, which I think misses the point. He still wants to access `a.func2()`, he just wants to get an error on this definition if `a` doesn't also extend `MyInterface`. Although maybe that wasn't clear in the question, that's what I gathered by reading his comments on other answers.

Comment: Yeah I didn't get that from the question as asked, but it makes sense that OP wants the class to know about that method... in which case your solution of not annotating and using `inferAs` is probably what I would do also. 

Answer (score 0):

Of course `a` is not assignable to `MyInterface` because `MyInterface` states that is has a `update` function, and not an `update` and a  `func2` fuction.

You either have to remove `func2` from the `a` declaration, or add `func2` to `MyInterface`

So both of the following will work:

```
interface MyInterface {
  update: () => void;
}

class MyClass {
  a: MyInterface = {
    update: function(){},
  }
}
```

```
interface MyInterface {
  update: () => void;
  func2: () => void;
}

class MyClass {
  a: MyInterface = {
    update: function(){},
    func2: function(){}
  }
}
```

Comment: And that is actually my question. I want to say the object only implements the interface so it can have other stuff as well. Like it works for classes.

Comment: No, that is not work like that, you can combine interfaces `a: MyInterface & MyInterface2`, or you can define `MyInterface ` as it can accept any other stuff like: `[key: string]: any;` below your update function type.

Comment: Note that [excess property checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) are the exception, not the rule.  The type `{update: () => void; func2: () => void}` is most definitely assignable to `{update: ()=>void}`.  It's only fresh object literals that are checked for extra properties.

Answer (score 0):

No. You need to comply to the interface in the implementation of it.

You may combine interfaces in your declaration of the variable `a` like so:

```
interface OtherInterfaceDeclaringFunc2 {
  func2: () => void;
}

...

  a: MyInterface & OtherInterfaceDeclaringFunc2 = {
    update: function(){},
    func2: function(){}
  }
```

Comment: Note that it *does* comply to the interface, but [excess property checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) prevent assignment in the case where you are assigning a fresh object literal to a place expecting a certain type.